# How do I reference a hash in the view and write an if/else statement around it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, hash

I have confirmed that app["rating"] == 0 in the rails console.  Given this, I am trying to write an if/else statement that will print out certain text but am having trouble doing so.

Any advice?

```
    <% if <%= app["rating"] %> == 0 %>
    no rating
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using ERB templates, you should be doing:

```
<% if app["rating"] == 0 %>
no rating
<% end %>
```

I don't know why you would nest your template declarations like that.

Remember that anything inside `<% ... %>` is evaluated as literal Ruby code. If you would like the result of that evaluation to be displayed, use `<%= ... %>`. Since you have non-Ruby code in there, the `if` will have the effect of either showing or not showing that part.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in between `<%` and `%>` is interpolated, so just do

```
<% if app["rating"] == 0 %>
  html content
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to nest the erb tags `<% %>` within your if statement. For example:

```
<% if app["rating"] == 0 %>
  no raiting
<% end %>
```

However, you're blurring the lines that MVC draws when you put conditional logic into your view. Without diving into discussions about presenters or DSLS, the simplest way to handle this would be to add a helper method.

Assuming this is in a controller called `apps_controller.rb` you would have a `apps_helper.rb` within the `/app/helpers` folder. You could create a helper method that looked something like this:

```
def display_rating(rating)
  rating = "No Rating" if rating == 0
  concat(rating)
end
```

Then, in your view you can use this helper by using `<%= display_rating(app["rating"]) %>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using ERB, to do an `if/else` statement you would do:

```
 <%if app["rating"] == 0 %>
   No Rating
   <%elsif app["rating"] == 10 %>
      rating 10 
   <%elsif app["rating"] == 20 %>
      rating 20
       etc...
 <% end %>
```

Comment: `<%=` is a bug here, as it will put the return 'true' into the page